# Do I need to clean up or remove event handlers after ajax load of grid & form content

Tags: jquery, plugins

After a click on a d/b table name, my 'admin' plugin loads a grid of table record rows, a jQuery-UI modal dialog input form and an OK To Delete modal form for that table. Event handlers are set for the grid row modify/delete buttons, column sort buttons, the optional pagination object. The form event handlers include setting the form values, validation and ajax submission.

Currently, the Ajax replaces the inner html of the 'content' div below

```
<div id='content'>
  <div id='deletemsg'></div>
  <div id='inputform'></div>
  <div id='grid'></div>
</div>
```

My question is what, if anything, do I have to do to remove/destroy the event code for the previous table data that has been replaced ?

Answer (score 1):

To remove the old events, you can use `unbind()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use "live" method to set the event handlers.
This way it'll affect the mark-up it finds, whether it's original table or replaced table, so, you don't have to worry about destroying/re-attaching events.

**Update:**

Going jQuery 1.7+, use `on()` instead of `live()`.

Details: http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html

Comment: Thanks ... I currently use delegate to catch events that bubble up the dom ... will check this out.

Comment: @user `live()` does the same thing internally, just a bit nicer to use :)

Comment: For anyone looking at this today, use .on() instead of .live(), which is deprecated.